# I want result in horizontal format in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have this code:

```
DECLARE
  V_RES varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..5 LOOP
    FOR J IN 65..70 LOOP
      V_RES := V_RES ||' '||I||CHR(J);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RES);
  V_RES :='';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The result is:

```
1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F
3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F
4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F
5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F
```

But I want the result in this format:

```
1A  2A  3A
1B  2B  3B
1C  2C  3C
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: So you want to swap your loops over? Why does your expected result only have three rows and columns instead of five?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to swap the order you loop over the characters and numbers; literally just swapping the two `for` statements would be enough:

```
DECLARE
  V_RES varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR J IN 65..70 LOOP
    FOR I IN 1..5 LOOP
      V_RES := V_RES ||' '||I||CHR(J);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RES);
  V_RES :='';
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

 1A 2A 3A 4A 5A
 1B 2B 3B 4B 5B
 1C 2C 3C 4C 5C
 1D 2D 3D 4D 5D
 1E 2E 3E 4E 5E
 1F 2F 3F 4F 5F
```

If you only want 1A to 3C, as you showed in the question, you would change the upper bound of each loop:

```
  FOR J IN 65..67 LOOP
    FOR I IN 1..3 LOOP
```

to get

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

 1A 2A 3A
 1B 2B 3B
 1C 2C 3C
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot Alex Poole